# How can I run an Eclipse plug-in written by me that automates Eclipse through its GUI using SWTBot

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swtbot

I wrote an Eclipse plug-in using `SWTBot` to automate Eclipse through its GUI. Actually I'm running this plug-in from Eclipse with Eclipse Application run configuration to test it. That opens a new Eclipse instance. After that I can start the plug-in with a `toolbarbutton` using `ui.actionSets` extension.

I'd like to start an Eclipse from command prompt and would like this plug-in to start automatically. In my case Eclipse shall be started with GUI of course.

Do you know any working solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`org.eclipse.ui.startup`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_startup.html) extension point. You need to provide a [`IStartup`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2FIStartup.html) implementing class that is called when the workbench is started.

Note: this is not a complete fail safe method, as the user is able to disable this extension point in the **Workbench > Startup** preference page.